# Upgrade couchdb/erlang on old Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, couchdb, ubuntu-10.04

I have an old Ubuntu 10.04 server running an old CouchDB server (1.0.1).

I want to upgrade CouchDB to latest version, but this needs a newer version of erlang. I tried with current repositories (lucid), but there's no upgrade to erlang.

I tried downloading the .deb file from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp but got various errors:

```
dpkg: considering removing erlang-base in favour of esl-erlang ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of erlang-base (--auto-deconfigure will help):
 erlang-crypto depends on erlang-base (= 1:13.b.3-dfsg-2ubuntu2.1) | erlang-base-hipe (= 1:13.b.3-dfsg-2ubuntu2.1)
  erlang-base is to be removed.
dpkg: regarding esl-erlang_16.b~ubuntu~lucid_amd64.deb containing esl-erlang:
 esl-erlang conflicts with erlang-base
  erlang-base (version 1:13.b.3-dfsg-2ubuntu2.1) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing esl-erlang_16.b~ubuntu~lucid_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing esl-erlang
Errors were encountered while processing:
 esl-erlang_16.b~ubuntu~lucid_amd64.deb
```

Server is used in producction, so I have not much chances to do something wrong.

Anybody knows a reliable way to upgrade CouchDB+erlang on this server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would try is setting up a 10.04 virtual machine on a non prod box to try out any fix first.  You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) if you don't have a vm host already. Install the repository erlang package to replicate your prod issue.

Once you have a safe environment to play in, try using the `--auto-deconfigure` option mentioned in the error message to get rid of the old Erlang version and install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

As the debian packages for CouchDB are usually quite old, I'd recommend to build both Erlang and CouchDB from source (Instructions for [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#How-to-Build-and-Install-ErlangOTP) and [CouchDB](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu)).

Of course kjw0188 is totally right that you should try everything in a VM first.

Some additional notes:

- If you have a reverse proxy in front of CouchDB this might make switching between the old and new database easier
- CouchDB 1.2 uses compression of the database files by default; Compression will be used (unless disabled in the config) on the first compaction after the update; Downgrading afterwards might be a problem.
- CouchDB 1.3 [changes the on-disk format](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.3.html#upgrade-notes) so downgrading will not be possible after the first compaction.